# Add a scroll bar for datatable in shiny when using wellPanel

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to add an X scroll bar for datatable when it's wrapped around a `fixedPanel`. See the following example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(), 
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput("table")
      ),
      fluidRow(
        DT::dataTableOutput("data2")
      )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["data"]] <-
        DT::renderDataTable({
         cbind(iris, iris, iris, iris, iris)[1, ]
        }, 
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          searching = FALSE,
          lengthChange = FALSE,
          paginate = FALSE,
          scroller = TRUE,
          scrollX = TRUE
        ))

      output[["table"]] <-
        renderUI({
          fixedPanel(
          wellPanel(div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', DT::dataTableOutput("data"))),
              style = "z-index: 10;"
          )
        })

      output[["data2"]] <-
        DT::renderDataTable({
          cbind(iris, iris, iris, iris, iris)
        }, 
        options = list(
          scroller = TRUE,
          scrollX = TRUE,
          pageLength = 25
        ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the opposite I could use the shiny `box` object and the scrolling works but then I don't have this datatable on top of other ui (`style = "z-index: 10;"`) that I need in my app:

```
      output[["table"]] <-
        renderUI({
          box(div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', DT::dataTableOutput("data")),
              width = 12,
              style = "z-index: 10;") # this line doesn't work

        })
```

Is it possible to combine the two? I'd rather use `fixedPanel` than `box`, but I need both components from datatable: scrolling and being on top of other ui output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574864/3439739

```
renderUI({
  fixedPanel(
    wellPanel(div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', DT::dataTableOutput("data"))),
        style = "z-index: 10; left:0; right:0; overflow-y:hidden; overflow-xy:auto"
  )
})
```

seems to do the job.