# HTML cut-off section

Tags: html, css

On my website the bottom of the page gets cut off. The solutions I have found online do not seem to work. Below I include the html section that is problematic.

```css
header{
  width:270px;
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Daniele Caratelli</h1>
  <p>
    Ph.D. candidate in Economics
    <br/>
    Stanford University
    <br/>
    <img src="at.png" width=150 height=17>
  </p>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/">Home</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/research.html">Research</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/teaching.html">Teaching</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/research/cv.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <p class="view"><img src="bikepic_circle.png" width=270 height=270></p>
  <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/danicaratelli" aria-label="@danicaratelli on GitHub">@danicaratelli</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Why are you using position: fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `float:left` and add `top:0;bottom:0` so that container is stretched from top to bottom and add `overflow:auto` to add scrollbar if required.

Similar question: [Have a fixed position div that needs to scroll if content overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094785/have-a-fixed-position-div-that-needs-to-scroll-if-content-overflows)

```css
header{
  width:270px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Daniele Caratelli</h1>
  <p>
    Ph.D. candidate in Economics
    <br/>
    Stanford University
    <br/>
    <img src="at.png" width=150 height=17>
  </p>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/">Home</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/research.html">Research</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/teaching.html">Teaching</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/research/cv.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <h3><p class="view"><a href="https://danicaratelli.github.io/extra.html">Extra</a></p></h3>
  <p class="view"><img src="bikepic_circle.png" width=270 height=270></p>
  <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/danicaratelli" aria-label="@danicaratelli on GitHub">@danicaratelli</a>
</header>
```